# How i can get the word who user type for a special word in non-english language in any language even c# , javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, unicode, keyboard-layout, hindi

Assume that a Non-English user types Namaste Duniya. I need to show  नमस्ते दुनिया  in Hindi Language. if i have  नमस्ते दुनिया stored in a variable then how i can get the word that was  typed by the user through keyboard and to show them in unicode. Like in this example namaste Duniya was typed for showing them नमस्ते दुनिया.

So my question is can I convert the chars to match the word they (users) typed in the keyboard? How i can do this in c# or any other language like javascript?

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Ade, I have edited his question, hope it's clearer now. I guess what he means is to do a match between unicode and the typed text of the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one seems to handle your texts

http://pinyin.info/tools/converter/chars2uninumbers.html

नमस्ते दुनिया
became `&#2344;&#2350;&#2360;&#2381;&#2340;&#2375; &#2342;&#2369;&#2344;&#2367;&#2351;&#2366;`

The code used is quite simple:

```
  var iString = "नमस्ते दुनिया", oString ="";
  for (var i=0; i<iString.length; i++) {
    oString += (iString.charCodeAt(i)<=127)? iString.charAt(i) : '&#' + iString.charCodeAt(i) + ';': 
  }
```

UPDATE:

If I understand the new text of the question, then something like

```
var translateLatin2Hindi = { 
"Namaste Duniya":"नमस्ते दुनिया",
,
,

"Duniya Namaste":"दुनिया नमस्ते"
}

var translateHindi2Latin = {}
for (var o in translateLatin2Hindi) {
  translateHindi2Latin[translateLatin2Hindi[o]]=o;
}
```

which then can be used as

```
function getHindi(latinString) {
  var val = translateLatin2Hindi[latinString];
  return (val)?val:"Not found";
}    
function getLatin(hindiString) {
  var val = translateHindi2Latin[hindiString];
  return (val)?val:"Not found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The original question was

> like Hello wolrd in Hindi it's was
>   नमस्ते दुनिया and user type in
>   keyboard for type it is
>
> namaste Duniya
>
> how i can get them namaste Duniya when
>   i have a text नमस्ते दुनिया

so I guess the question is either about transliteration of Hindi, or about mapping output (Unicode) characters to key sequences on the keyboard.

(just a hint for those fluent in Hindi keyboard mappings)

Comment: I thought that the OP wants to have specific words that he knows how to translate and just do a replacement for those.